# What would be the robust design pattern for multiple class forms render/process (create, update) on single page in django

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I am working on a django project in which I have to design a sales order page for order processing,now as per requirement I have to create multiple information forms on single page with different fields (**formset** does not helpful in this case) which I achieved by creating specific form class and then render them in template through class view function

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CreateOrderView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['ord_info_form'] = OrderInformationForm()
    context['billing_form'] = BillingInformationForm(prefix='billing')
    context['shipping_form'] = ShipingInformationForm(prefix='shipping')
    context['payment_form'] = PaymentInfoForm()
    context['summary_form'] = OrderProductsForm()
    return context
```

My template look like this:

[image]

Now, I have to save data for all forms which belongs to multiple models like billing, contact and shipping information. So for save information I created another form class for create order and set it in **form_class** variable in Createview class, and I override the save function in form class in which I manipulate the data for all model forms. For update order (put operation) I did the same I create another form class for update like create one in form class.

As per my understanding I implement this strategy, but this seems to me repetitive design. How can I design it better for multiple forms with different fields. Please let me know what kind of design pattern I can apply for this.

P.S: If require I'll post more code and assets for clear understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying you created _two_ distinct form classes, one for the createview and the other for the updateview ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: Yes actually, I am not using single class because of multiple conditions in save function for update case. This is the reason I am looking for a robust pattern.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:

1. Build a stable(take your time here, you don't want any redundant data) database using django [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/).
2. Use [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to build proper [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) and [validators](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/) against every model.
3. Route them to urls and perform other linking operations on your [views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).
4. Choose a javascript framework, you are comfortable with([Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/),[Angular2](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart),[React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) which ever you want) and write the frontend separately(this part will have your multiple forms and stuff).
5. Use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to post your data in [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/).

This is my personal suggestion, you can also go for django formsets but that will not be suitable in your example.

Comment: My requirement does not allow me to use DRF, I've to design this backend only in pure django.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on exactly the same requirement. What we have done is the following:

1. Create the classbasedview to render the forms and add them to the context just as you did on the top.
2. I see you've created the template based on the forms you added to the context, but as someone else pointed out you need to use an alternative rather than just django to make the post of each item. In my case I used plain old ajax to perform my post. So it looks something like this:

   ```
   function firePost() {
   var endpoint = '/sales_center/orders/add';
   var channel = getChannelForm();
   var order = getOrderForm()
   var ip = getIPForms();
   var collections = getCollections();
   var subscriptions = getBookSubs();
   var perpetual = getBookPerp();
   $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: endpoint,
       data: {
           'order':JSON.stringify(order),
           'channel': JSON.stringify(channel),
           'ips':JSON.stringify(ip),
           'collections': JSON.stringify(collections),
           'subscriptions': JSON.stringify(subscriptions),
           'perpetual': JSON.stringify(perpetual)
       },
       success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
       }
   });
   }
   ```
3. In the data section I divided the information by name. My order is composed of a channel, multiple collections, multiple ips, multiple subscriptions and multiple perpetual purchases. The endpoint is the same as the one in the page so in the backend in order to process that we do it like this:

   ```
   @transaction.atomic
   def post(self, request):
      channel = self._create_channel(json.loads(request.POST.get('channel')))
       order = self._create_order(json.loads(request.POST.get('order')), canal)
       ips = self._assign_ips(json.loads(request.POST.get('ips')), canal)
       return JsonResponse({}, status=200)
   ```
4. The code above is just an example the **_create_channel** is a function in our classbasedview. Each function performs the posts in our backend for each model. That way it looks clean and easy to read each step of the order.
5. I added the **@transaction.atomic** to perform
   any rollbacks in case in one critical step of the order we have
   inconsistent data and we need to rollback or delete the data saved before in the database.
6. In each function we then use the forms we sent on the template in the context data, we use them to save or get errors in case something isn't filled out correctly. We do something like this:

   ```
   def _create_channel(self, data):
       form = ChannelForm(data)

       if form.is_valid():
           new_channel = form.save(commit=False)
           new_channel.save()

           return new_channel
       else:
           return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
   ```

I hope the example above helps you.